# Opening some of the links inside the webView in the browser( only some not all)

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview app for my site , i want opensome of the links in my site in the browser when the user click , and other link inside the webView  ...only some no all!! and link in my site no in my app!!

for example!!! in this cod in url contain sms toast url:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);

    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
   web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

    web.loadUrl(url);
      String weburl = web.getUrl();
    if(weburl.contains("sms")){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text =weburl;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;


        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

    }
```

tank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method of the `WebViewClient`.

Example (taken from the official doc):

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of this new `WebViewClient` for the `WebView`:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation